# Получить ссылку на картинку с помощью $js=file_get_contents

Tags: php, javascript, json

Пожалуйста, помогите вытащить url адрес картинки с помощью $js=file_get_contents
Ссылку и содержимое h2 вытащить могу, картинку нет.
Мой код:

```
if(preg_match_all("/<a.*?href=\"(.*?)\">.*?<h2.*?>(.*?)<\/h2>/s", $js, 
$matches))
{
$n = count($matches[1]);
$html = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
{
$item->title = $matches[2][$i];
$item->url = $matches[1][$i];
```

Картинка в исходном коде:
`<img id="banner" src="/i/product/thumb/420/42095.jpg" style="width: 90px; height: 90px; top: 7px; left: 0px; position: static;border:0px;">`

Нужно что-то подобное     `$item->img = $matches..........;`

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например можно так. Но это костыль, как и то, что вы делаете с регуляркой

```
$str = '<img id="banner" src="/i/product/thumb/420/42095.jpg"">';
$str = str_split($str);
$src = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($str); $i++) {
    if ($str[$i] == 's' && $str[$i + 1] == 'r' && $str[$i + 2] == 'c' && $str[$i + 3] == '=') {
        $begin = $i + 5;
        while ($str[$begin] != '"') {
            $src .= $str[$begin++];
        }
    }
}

echo $src;
```

Правильное решение - парсить html. 
Пример библиотеки: https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser

```
// Assuming you installed from Composer:
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;

$dom = new Dom;
$dom->loadStr('<img id="banner" src="/i/product/thumb/420/42095.jpg">', []);
$i = $dom->find('img')[0];
echo $i->getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: У меня все переписывать придется если библиотеку подключать, поздно о ней узнал. Мне предложили такой вариант `preg_match_all('@<img id="banner" src="(.*?)"@smi');
` но как его вставить в `if(preg_match_all("/<a.*?href=\"(.*?)\">.*?<h2.*?>(.*?)<\/h2>/s", $js,` не понимаю...

Comment: Я предложил Вам костыль. Всё переписывать - это проблемы Вашего качества кода, которые никак не влияют на правильность моего ответа.

Comment: Так я претензий и не предъявляю :) Понимаю, что ваш код вернее моего. Просто мне нужно с моим что-то сделать.

Comment: Так а чем конкретно костыль то не устроил?) Вполне работает же))

Comment: У меня есть строка которая получает url и содержимое h2, в нее и нужно воткнуть получение картинки `if(preg_match_all("/<a.*?href=\"(.*?)\">.*?<h2.*?>(.*?)<\/h2>/s", $js, 
$matches))`. Можно воткнуть это `preg_match_all('@<img id="banner" src="(.*?)"@smi');` но как?